# What is calling requestWhenInUseAuthorization?

Tags: xcode, react-native

I am working on a react-native app. I send it to Testflight. Apple says it's missing `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription`. However, I don't see where is my app asking for location data? The app doesn't show a prompt for it. I looked at the code, and nowhere is it actually calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization` nor `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`.

How can I find out what is calling `requestAlwaysAuthorization` or `requestWhenInUseAuthorization`? Does XCode allow to have some breakpoint for those functions?

Thank you,

Slackware

Comment: It isn't necessarily your app, sometimes 3rd party libraries want it. Any action by a 3rd party is your responsibility.

Comment: I checked my node_modules and nothing actually calls. There is an `if` block that calls it, but that `if` block is not exercised